# Focus does not appear to work consistently

Tags: python, tkinter-entry

I am frustrated by something that works in one place then doesn't a few lines later.
I have an entrybox for entering a value. It must be entered so it tests for input and if there is none it gives an info message saying so. On clicking 'OK' the focus is returned to the same entrybox until a value is inserted. Here is the snippet of code: (eOdometer is the entrybox)

```
def Calc_dist(event):
    if event.widget == eOdometer:
        if len(eOdometer.get()) == 0:
           msgbox.showwarning(title="No input",message="You have not entered a value")
           eOdometer.focus()
        elif  int(eOdometer.get()) < int(Odo2):
               msgbox.showwarning(title="Wrong kilometers",message="The Kms are less than previous input")
               eOdometer.delete(0,tk.END)
               eOdometer.focus()
        else:
                Odo1=eOdometer.get()
```

etc.
**Look at eOdometer.focus()**

Now, just a little later I test whether a different entrybox has received a value. If not it brings up a askyesno messagebox. If the reply is yes it should return focus to the entrybox to get a value but it does not do so. Instead it moves on to the next entrybox. I cannot see why the focus() function works in one place but not in the next. Here is the code: (eFuelQ is the entrybox)

```
    EconVal = tk.StringVar()
def Calc_Econ(event):
  if event.widget == eFuelQ:
       global answer
       if not len(eFuelQ.get())==0:
            Odo1=eOdometer.get()
            FuelQuant=eFuelQ.get()
            print("Fuel quantity is :" + FuelQuant)
            Distance=int(Odo1)-Odo2
            print("Odo1="+str(Odo1))
            print("Odo2="+str(Odo2))
            EconVal.set(round(float(Distance)/float(FuelQuant),2))
            print("Economy is",EconVal.get())
       else:
            answer= msgbox.askyesno(title="No Data",message="Did you put in fuel?")
       if answer:
            print("Yes I did")
            eFuelQ.focus()
       else:
            print("No I didn't")
            eFuelQ.insert(0,"0.00")
            eFuelA.insert(0,"0.00")
```

**Look at eFuelQ.focus()**

Comment: Which event is bound to trigger `Calc_Econ()`? I think you need to add `return "break"` after `eFuelQ.focus()`.

Comment: Once again, thank you very much for your assistance. The trigger to the solution was your question asking which event Calc_Econ() was bound to. I realised that I should split the binding to two separate events and then everything worked just fine. Thanks.